# Electrolux vacuum lightbulb keeps burning out?

Tags: electrical, lighting, appliances

Asking for a relative. Older Electrolux Canister Vacuum with a light in the power head. May be model 6500. Bulbs keep burning out quickly. In a month he's gone through 4 bulbs.

Any idea what could be causing this and what can be done to correct it?

Update: He wound up taking it in for repair and the belt needed to be replaced and there was something blocking the rollers from spinning. This was causing excessive heat which was contributing the to bulbs burning out so quickly according to the repair person.

Comment: Does the vacuum work without the light?  The simple solution is to stop vacuuming in the dark, so you don't need the headlight.

Comment: Yeah works fine. It's not my vacuum so not my call. He likes the light to see while vacuuming underthings.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like its a B15 bayonet base, try https://www.ecolume.co.uk see if they have one in LED.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to vibration from the motor -- try a hard-service or "fan service" light bulb; LED replacement bulbs may also be a better choice than regular incandescent or CFL bulbs in this application.

Comment: This is not a generic bulb and the vacuum is very old and has only had this problem recently. OEM and 3rd party bulbs meant for this vacuum have had issues.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY -- very odd indeed; are all the replacement bulbs incandescent, or are LED replacements having the same problem?

Comment: I don't know of any LED bulbs with that base so nne have been used. If you know of any please let me know but these types of bulbs are supposed to work in this installation and have successfully in the past. I'm wondering if there could somehow be a problem with the socket that may be causing arcing. One more note, after the bulb burns out it gets black from what I'm told if that makes a difference.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY -- what type of base/socket is it?

Comment: Hmm... i thought I put the link in one of my other comments.. guess not http://evacuumstore.com/p-7823-electrolux-epic-6500-bulb.aspx

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY -- looking at the photo, it appears to be a bayonet type lamp base -- what diameter is it?

Comment: I don't have the bulbs anymore but they were somewhere around 2.5-3" long and maybe about 1/2" diameter at the base? I'm primarily interested in what might be causing the bulbs to die so quickly because if it's something in the power head causing a problem how do I know it may not burn out even an LED bulb. The vacuum, the areas vacuumed and the person doing the vacuuming haven't changed so the bulbs should be having the same stress they previously had but for some reason they burn out quickly.